# How do i use regex and route parameters in expressjs?

Tags: regex, express

I can't find the full pattern behind route parameters and regular expressions expressjs.

This matches:

route: exemple.com/users/123456

```
// Regex rule for route parameter
app.get( '^/users/:userId([0-9]{6})', function( req, res ) {
    res.send( 'Route match for User ID: ' + req.params.userId );
} );
```

This doesn't match:

route: exemple.com/us-en

```
app.use('/:countryAndLanguage(\w{2}-\w{2})',homepageRouter);
```

What am i not seeing..

Comment: Not an express user, but the expression looks fine to me. Do you get a value for the key when you try to log it? `app.use('/:countryAndLanguage(\w{2}-\w{2})', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('key:', req.params.countryAndLanguage);
    next();
});`

Comment: Thank you for your responds. 

It does not reach the console.log function you created.

When i do remove the regex part i get the prop and key value.

app.use('/:countryAndLanguage', function (req, res, next) { console.log('key:', req.params.countryAndLanguage); next(); });

wft is going on here.

Comment: This does work. app.use('/:countryAndLanguage([0-9a-z-]+)',homepageRouter);

Comment: Omg. Fixed it. I will answer my own question.

Comment: Weird. Since Express seems to create a JavaScript regex object in the background, `\w{2}` should be supported. You can test expressions against routes [here](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/). Maybe an Express version issue? Or maybe one of your other routes already reacts to strings formed like `/us-en`?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says the following:

> Because the regular expression is usually part of a literal string, be
>   sure to escape any \ characters with an additional backslash, for
>   example \d+.

source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

So it was just a simple escape that I forgot.. . Finale answer:

```
app.use('/:countryAndLanguage(\\w{2}-\\w{2})',homepageRouter);
```

Comment: Ah, string interpolation, of course. Should have anticipated that, lol. Good on you. :)